# Scrapy with proxies using downloader middleware

Tags: python, proxy, scrapy

I'm new to Scrapy and I am trying to build my own Downloader Middleware in order to go through a proxy to scrape the web. I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/bli1/Development/projects/hinwin/chisel/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1128, in _inlineCallbacks
    result = g.send(result)
  File "/Users/bli1/Development/projects/hinwin/chisel/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 90, in crawl
    six.reraise(*exc_info)
  File "/Users/bli1/Development/projects/hinwin/chisel/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 72, in crawl
    self.engine = self._create_engine()
  File "/Users/bli1/Development/projects/hinwin/chisel/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 97, in _create_engine
    return ExecutionEngine(self, lambda _: self.stop())
  File "/Users/bli1/Development/projects/hinwin/chisel/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/core/engine.py", line 68, in __init__
    self.downloader = downloader_cls(crawler)
  File "/Users/bli1/Development/projects/hinwin/chisel/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/core/downloader/__init__.py", line 88, in __init__
    self.middleware = DownloaderMiddlewareManager.from_crawler(crawler)
  File "/Users/bli1/Development/projects/hinwin/chisel/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/middleware.py", line 58, in from_crawler
    return cls.from_settings(crawler.settings, crawler)
  File "/Users/bli1/Development/projects/hinwin/chisel/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/middleware.py", line 34, in from_settings
    mwcls = load_object(clspath)
  File "/Users/bli1/Development/projects/hinwin/chisel/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/utils/misc.py", line 44, in load_object
    mod = import_module(module)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named downloaders.downloader_middlewares.proxy_connect
```

This error is due to `Scrapy` not being able to find my middleware. I'm not sure if this is caused because I'm not setting up the correct path or if I am doing something wrong with my middleware.

This is my project structure:

```
/chisel
    __init__.py
    pipelines.py
    items.py
    settings.py
    /downloaders
        __init__.py
        /downloader_middlewares
            __init__.py
        proxy_connect.py
        /resources
          config.json
    /spiders
        __init__.py
        craiglist_spider.py
        /spider_middlewares
            __init__.py
        /resources
          craigslist.json
scrapy.cfg
```

Within my my settings.py I have

```
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'downloaders.downloader_middlewares.proxy_connect.ProxyConnect': 100,
    'scrapy.contrib.downloadermiddleware.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware': 110
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#activating-a-downloader-middleware) the path should include the project (`'myproject.middlewares.CustomDownloaderMiddleware'`) in your case I think it should be:

```
'chisel.downloaders.downloader_middlewares.proxy_connect.ProxyConnect': 100
```